# Javascript String handling Probably Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to find a way to test a string to specific problem.

Let me example:

the string is : **"Bella und Chris kaufen ein Brot, ein Stück Käse und eine Packung Butter"** or

it can be like this : **"Bella und Chris kaufen ein Brot, ein Stück Käse, eine Packung Butter"**

The problem is that "Bella und Chris kaufen " part can be same and other's can be different like changing their position.

like this: **"Bella und Chris kaufen ein Stück Käse, ein Brot, eine Packung Butter"**

or : **"Bella und Chris kaufen ein Stück Käse, eine Packung Butter, ein Brot"**

and so on.

```
var cn = ["Bella und Chris kaufen ", "ein Stück Käse", "eine Packung Butter", "ein Brot"];
//User should write like this: control[1][0]+control[1][1]+", "+control[1][2]+" und "+control[1][3]
//or this : control[1][0]+control[1][1]+", "+control[1][2]+", "+control[1][3]
```

I need to take user's input and check if the string is okey with these two condition. I look for a Regex can handle my problem but couln't find one.

Comment: Does `Bella und Chris kaufen (?:(?:ein Brot|ein Stück Käse|eine Packung Butter)(?:$|, | und )){3}` work as you expect?

Comment: I would recommend against trying to do NLP with regexp.

Comment: Helloa @torazaburo, can you please explane what is NLP :)

Comment: Hello @Rawing, that works for me but repeating shouldn't have an option for user. can we fix that ?

Comment: Natural Language Processing.

Comment: Thanks @torazaburo I'll check about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this.

**Note: In these demos the multiline flag is on (meaning `^` matches the start of the *line* and `$` matches the end of the line)**

`\bBella und Chris kaufen(?:(?: (ein Stück Käse|eine Packung Butter|ein Brot)(?=,| und|$)(?!.*?\1)(?: und|,?)))+\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/47M2OX/3))

or if you aren't concerned about repeated phrases. Depending on the source of input, they might not be a concern

`\bBella und Chris kaufen(?:(?: (ein Stück Käse|eine Packung Butter|ein Brot)(?=,| und|$)(?: und|,?)))+\b` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/47M2OX/2))

But the trouble is that it appears you're only showing us a sentence fragment? What follows after

`Bella und Chris kaufen ein Stück Käse, ein Brot, eine Packung Butter`***`[...]`***?

If it's the end of the string (thus no end punctuation), you can use the regex as I've written. Likewise if it's the end of a line (multiple samples in one input.

If it's a period, you can change `$` and the final `\b` to `[.]`. If it can be any sentence-ending punctuation, you can change both occurrences to `[.!?]`.

---

**Update:**

You should probable make an array of must-have phrases

`var Snacks = ["ein Stück","Käse|eine Packung Butter","ein Brot"]`

And via callback function, evaluate if your string contains each phrase

```
var regex = /^Bella und Chris kaufen(?:(?: ((ein Stück Käse)|(eine Packung Butter)|(ein Brot))(?=,| und|$)(?!.*?\1)(?: und|,?)))+\b/gm;
var picnic = `Bella und Chris kaufen ein Brot, ein Stück Käse und eine Packung Butter

Bella und Chris kaufen ein Brot, ein Stück Käse, eine Packung Butter

Bella und Chris kaufen ein Brot, eine Packung Butter und ein Brot
^ repeats ein Brot twice, as a sample.

Bella und Chris kaufen ein Stück Käse, eine Packung Butter, ein Brot`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
var result = picnic.replace(regex, function(m) {
  // loop through Snacks
  // see if picnic contains each snack element, if it doesn't, append it
);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Hello @Regular Joe, Thanks for your answer, i need one more thing about it, when user write one of those missing, it shouldn't be correct like this: "Bella und Chris kaufen ein Brot, ein Stück Käse". and i don't know how to do that :(
I want to learn, but idk where..